# No handler found for uri [/<url>/<url>] and method [PUT]

Tags: php, arrays, json, elasticsearch

I am receiving the `No handler found for uri [/<url>/<url>] and method [PUT]` error when sending a request via Elasticsearch.

I am using POST, not PUT, so I do not need to use _id. Using POST is mandatory. The following request worked until adding 'archive' index.

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'servers',
            'type' => 'servers',
            'body' => [
                'servername' => $servername,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'location' => $location,
                'ping' => $ping,
                'archive' => 0
            ]
        ];
        $response = $client->index($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding the index and changing `archive` to a string, as opposed to an int, resolved the issue.

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'servers',
            'type' => 'servers',
            'body' => [
                'servername' => $servername,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'location' => $location,
                'ping' => $ping,
                'archive' => "0"
            ]
        ];
        $response = $client->index($params);
```